# Strange characters() behavior with SAX + Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, character, sax

In my XML I have a multi-line element:

```
<tag id="sometag" ...>
    | first line
    |     second line
    |         third line
    |     fourth line
<tag ...>
....
<tag id="someothertag" ...>
    | ANOTHER FIRST LINE
    |     ANOTHER SECOND LINE
    |         ANOTHER THIRD LINE
    |     ANOTHER FORTH LINE
<tag ...>
```

And then in Java I have the necessary `startElement`, `endElement`, and `characters` methods, but I find I get some strange behavior with `characters`:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){
    Log.d(TAG, "characters( "\"" + (new String(ch)).replaceAll("[\r\n]", "\\n") + "\", " + start + ", " + length + " )");
}
```

Besides that I do nothing to the characters. I'm basically creating two instances of a parser. With one instance I'm search for `sometag`. I throw an exception if I find what I'm looking for and return that element.

```
D/MyProgram( 1565): STARTING document parsing...
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n   ", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        | first line", 0, 20 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       | first line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   second line", 0, 23 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |   second line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |       third line", 0, 26 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |       third line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   fourth lineline", 0, 22 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |   fourth lineline", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   fourth lineline", 0, 4 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): Successfully found "sometag"!
```

...and with the other completely new instance I'm searching for `someothertag`. I do the same thing as before.

```
D/MyProgram( 1565): STARTING document parsing...
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "    ", 0, 4 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n   ", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        | first line", 0, 20 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       | first line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   second line", 0, 23 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |   second line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |       third line", 0, 26 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |       third line", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   fourth lineline", 0, 22 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |   fourth lineline", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        |   fourth lineline", 0, 4 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): Successfully found "someothertag"!
```

I understand that XML parsing is stream-based (it parses chunks instead of the entire string) but this is very strange behavior. Here are a few things I notice that are really confusing:

- With each iteration of characters(), the parser isn't starting where it left off or finishing the characters if it, indeed, finish parsing: I'm even getting characters that are *before* the first char array ('`n`', which is a replacement of a newline character).
- `ch` has extra characters that weren't there originally: "`line`" is appended to "`forth line`".
- When I create a completely new instance of the parser, the characters are "re-read." The second execution should read something like:

..this...

```
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "    ", 0, 4 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n   ", 0, 1 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "        | ANOTHER FIRST LINE", 0, 20 )
D/MyProgram( 1565): characters( "n       |     ANOTHER SECOND LINE", 0, 1 )
```

... and so on.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you aren't respecting start and length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Margulies says, you're not using `start` and `length` within the passed character array.

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
    // use only the indicated segment.
    String str = new String( ch, start, length);  
    Log.d(TAG, "characters( "\"" + str.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "\\n") + "\", " + start + ", " + length + " )");
}
```

Comment: Another problem I had was that the string builder for the parser was static. I needed to reset it using builder.setLength().